# Disable robots.txt check in nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I wanna disable robots.txt checking in [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) and crawl everything from websites.
`Disable` means before fetching or parsing any website, skip checking robot.txt.
Is this possible?

Comment: You **really shouldn't** do this. It looks like the project is shipped as source code under _Apache License, Version 2.0_, so you could edit the lines in `RobotRules` or `RobotRulesParser` to treat every URL as "allowed". If you make any changes here you should add something to the user agent to reflect that it isn't a normal version of the software.

Comment: i'm looking for a way to disable using configuration not to change the code.

Comment: at this [link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Ignoring-Robots-txt-td619276.html) there is a discussion for similar question. I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i understand we are not able to disable robots.txt in nutch.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is old,I would personally feel it is still relevant to answer.

yes, it possible to disable **robots.txt** flow (but you need Nutch source code change and build).

**Note: nutch does not provide any specific conf to disable robots.txt fetch before fetching actual URL. because what you are saying just sounds like URL/domain abuse and you want to access it irrespective of what the website is trying to say about its resources via robots.txt.**

**How it is possible?**
If you have a custom use case where you genuinely need to skip robots.txt then you can do following things

most of the plugins(protocal-(http|httpclient|selenium|okhttp)) in nutch uses **HttpRobotRulesParser** class to fetch and parse the content of robots.txt

In **HttpRobotsRulesParser** this particular method where you can parse and return **rules object**.

```
public BaseRobotRules getRobotRulesSet(Protocol http, URL url,
      List<Content> robotsTxtContent) {

    if (LOG.isTraceEnabled() && isWhiteListed(url)) {
      LOG.trace("Ignoring robots.txt (host is whitelisted) for URL: {}", url);
    }

    String cacheKey = getCacheKey(url);
    BaseRobotRules robotRules = CACHE.get(cacheKey);

    if (robotRules != null) {
      return robotRules; // cached rule
    } else if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      LOG.trace("cache miss " + url);
    }

    boolean cacheRule = true;
    URL redir = null;

    if (isWhiteListed(url)) {
      // check in advance whether a host is whitelisted
      // (we do not need to fetch robots.txt)
      robotRules = EMPTY_RULES;
      LOG.info("Whitelisted host found for: {}", url);
      LOG.info("Ignoring robots.txt for all URLs from whitelisted host: {}",
          url.getHost());

    } else {
      try {
        URL robotsUrl = new URL(url, "/robots.txt");
        Response response = ((HttpBase) http).getResponse(robotsUrl,
            new CrawlDatum(), false);
        if (robotsTxtContent != null) {
          addRobotsContent(robotsTxtContent, robotsUrl, response);
        }
        // try one level of redirection ?
        if (response.getCode() == 301 || response.getCode() == 302) {
          String redirection = response.getHeader("Location");
          if (redirection == null) {
            // some versions of MS IIS are known to mangle this header
            redirection = response.getHeader("location");
          }
          if (redirection != null) {
            if (!redirection.startsWith("http")) {
              // RFC says it should be absolute, but apparently it isn't
              redir = new URL(url, redirection);
            } else {
              redir = new URL(redirection);
            }

            response = ((HttpBase) http).getResponse(redir, new CrawlDatum(), false);
            if (robotsTxtContent != null) {
              addRobotsContent(robotsTxtContent, redir, response);
            }
          }
        }

        if (response.getCode() == 200) // found rules: parse them
          robotRules = parseRules(url.toString(), response.getContent(),
              response.getHeader("Content-Type"), agentNames);

        else if ((response.getCode() == 403) && (!allowForbidden))
          robotRules = FORBID_ALL_RULES; // use forbid all
        else if (response.getCode() >= 500) {
          //cacheRule = false; // try again later to fetch robots.txt
          robotRules = EMPTY_RULES;
        } else
          robotRules = EMPTY_RULES; // use default rules
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
          LOG.info("Couldn't get robots.txt for " + url + ": " + t.toString());
        }
        //cacheRule = false; // try again later to fetch robots.txt
        robotRules = EMPTY_RULES;
      }
    }

    if (cacheRule) {
      CACHE.put(cacheKey, robotRules); // cache rules for host
      if (redir != null && !redir.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(url.getHost())
          && "/robots.txt".equals(redir.getFile())) {
        // cache also for the redirected host
        // if the URL path is /robots.txt
        CACHE.put(getCacheKey(redir), robotRules);
      }
    }

    return robotRules;
  }
```

you can go ahead and replace with below method

```
  @Override
  public BaseRobotRules getRobotRulesSet(Protocol http, URL url,
      List<Content> robotsTxtContent) {
       return EMPTY_RULES; // always return empty rules to skip robots.txt access.
    }
```

you are just mocking the behavior with returning EMPTY_RULES.

Imp note: It is always advisable to read and access resources as mentioned in robots.txt.

Comment: In one of my project, I have also do the same thing, for this I have customized Fetcher Reducer class. It works fine for my case.